# Creating polygon from polyline

Tags: python, open-source, polygon, polyline

I have a road network shapefile as a polyline and I want to convert this to a polygon layer wherever the network forms a 'hole' or closes in on itself. The problem is a hole could be made from more than one road feature. (i.e. three connecting roads form a hole). This means that I cant just say "if the first feature vertext is equal to the last vertex form a polygon."

I only have access to open source modules (PySAL, shapely etc NOT ArcPy)

Any ideas? Been stuck on this one for way too long!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can iterate through the points,

- And at each point compare to all points examined so far.
- - If there's a match, close-off a polygon.

Not sure if you're going to get much better than O(n^2).